# Why did a mod close this question on indemnity forms as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A mod closed the question [What is the point of indemnity forms if the ICAO rules state the airlines can recover the costs for removing inadmissible persons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/176799/1810) as opinion-based. The accepted answer shows there is a non-opinion-based answer:

> Because the passenger has a contract with the airline and is not obviously directly bound by an international agreement like the ICAO convention. Furthermore, the 'transportation costs' mentioned in the ICAO convention are usually just a tiny part of the actual costs incurred for the airline, which they will or may try to get back from the passenger (potentially depending on national interpretation of the wording).

The question had 3 old close votes before the accepted answer was posted 5 days ago. However, a mod just closed the question using their mod priviledge. Why did a mod close this question as opinion-based?

Answer (score 0):

This mod did cast a close vote as this mod does not think this question belongs on this site.
As several votes had already been cast, the opinion based reason was the one that would have been added to the close message.

Said mod did go with the other votes, but whatever reason the mod would have entered, the close reason would have been given as 'opinion based'.

Good luck with collecting re-opening votes.

(Mods are only people, with opinions and if handling 15 questions in a queue they may not spend hours on each question they review, so going with the flow is a reasonable action.)

Comment: The question had 3 old close votes before the accepted answer was posted 5 days ago, and no non-mod close votes afterward. The accepted answer shows there is a non-opinion-based answer. What do you think is opinion-based in "Because the passenger has a contract with the airline and is not obviously directly bound by an international agreement like the ICAO convention."?

Comment: That one non opinion based answer is possible does not make the question fit on the site. I would have chosen 'does not fit this site, is not about travel as used here.'

Comment: Knowing what indemnity forms entail is important for travelers. Therefore the question in on topic here.

Comment: @Franck - by that logic I could ask a question about rucksacks here, as they are important for travellers. You are not correct. Questions here need to meet all the requirements of this site, including quality requirements.

Comment: With that question in particular, you may get more luck asking on Law.SE, but again, read their site guidelines first to make sure you don't get it rejected for not meeting them.

Comment: @RoryAlsop indemnity forms are only given to travelers. They are specific to traveling. It's part of the travel experience. It's a travel paperwork. It falls under the topics "modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport" and "finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange" on https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Nobody except the mod had cast any off topic close vote.

Comment: You think it falls on topic. I disagree. I would have also added a close vote if it wasn't already closed when I saw it

Comment: "I disagree" -> how about you explain your viewpoint? I explained mine. The question has 233 views and only 1 off-topic close vote.

Comment: Just a quick correction/tidbit of knowledge: *whatever reason the mod would have entered, the close reason would have been given as 'opinion based'* isn't true. If a moderator closes the question, the (top-level) close reason they select will override the other voters' reasons. See [this global meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339400/how-does-the-system-determine-which-one-close-reason-should-be-displayed-on-a-cl) that documents the system's process for selecting the final close reason based on the close votes cast.

Comment: @gparyani thanks for sharing. I wish one could see the close reason for all close voters.